# Where clause in elasticsearch UpdateRequest

Tags: elasticsearch, updates

I have an elasticsearch index where the id is auto-generated. When the need comes to update any document I have to search the document (using other parameters) to get the id first and then use this id in the update request.

Is there a way in which I can provide the where clause in update request itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct support for this.
But then there is a community driven plugin which can be used for it.
This plugin can update documents based on a search condition.

You can find it here - https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Script functionality of `UpdateRequest`. The where condition can be provided using if statement.

Example:

```
updateRequest.script(new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless",
    "if (ctx._source.userName== 'XXX') {ctx._source.age= '21'}",Collections.emptyMap()));
```